# Connecting Android in Eclipse with WAMP server

Tags: php, android, eclipse, wamp

Hi I am newbie to Android development and in particular to connecting to servers from apps. I am currently attempting to connect my android app to a database on a WAMP server. I hope in the future to use this as a means to login but for the mean time I am just looking to retrieve the data that I have stored within the database. I am really confused with all of this at the moment and have looked at numerous tutorials and my code looks to be the exact same as the code which is posted within all of the tutorials and I have followed all of the steps.

I would be very grateful to anyone out there who could help me with this as I am truely stuck on this and unable to find a solution to my problem.

Thanks very much. Please find below my code..

```
    package eoghan.android;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity; 
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.net.ParseException;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class FoodPHPActivity extends Activity {



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb=null;

        //http post
        try{
              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/wamp/www/Food/food.php");

              List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
              nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Food_Name", "Apple"));  

              httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
              HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
              HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              is = entity.getContent();
              Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass 123 ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }

        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        //parsing data
        int fd_id = 0;
        String fd_name = null;

        try{
            System.out.println("Entering the try method to connect the JSON");

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

            JSONObject json_data=null;
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    fd_id=json_data.getInt("Food_ID");
                    fd_name=json_data.getString("Food_Name");
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "JSON works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        }
        catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Food Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        catch (ParseException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
         }

        System.out.println(fd_id);
        System.out.println(fd_name);

    }

}
```

I have included the line:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

and have followed several other worked examples yet with no success.

I really would appreciate any help that would aid me with this.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: unless you want us to guess your exact error, how about you paste the logcat error here instead?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pointing to an external IP address. Do you have the port forwarding and everything set up correctly on your home network?  Maybe you should set up a simple HTML page to test if you can at least access it from the outside without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hey It seems there is no problem with code may be the problem with Wamp server configuration connection  make sure your Wamp server is working properly and just go to any internet browser and hit the localhost url and try your(localhost/wamp/www/Food/food.php) Url also..

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("[http://10.0.2.2/wamp/www/Food/food.php](LINK)");
```

with this line:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("[http://10.0.2.2/Food/food.php](LINK)");
```

Comment: Why wouldn't this URL be valid?